# libxml/tree.h file not found for tests

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, libxml2

I'm using libxml in a project. I had an issue before where the app would not compile due to a "Lexical or Preprocessor issue" in which the file libxml/tree.h could not be found. I fixed this by copying the library into my projects root folder and adding the Header Search Path: "${SDKROOT}/usr/include/libxml2".

This fixed the original issue. However, whenever my unit tests have a dependency on any part of the project with an ultimate dependency upon libxml2, the same problem occurs. My project still compiles fine, just not when I'm try to run unit tests.

I'm quite new to objective-c/iOS so I'm really clueless. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out that I had set the header search path "${SDKROOT}/usr/include/libxml2" in the main app target, but in order to use the library in my unit tests the header search path must also be set in the "[App name]Tests" target settings.